# Serving file to user

Tags: jquery, file

I have the following code:

```
$.post("./test.php", {
    record:id,
    opt:'code'
  },
  function(data){$('#div').html('').queue(function() {
    $('#div').html(data).dequeue();
  });
});
```

`data` returns the file name, for example "test.xlx". How do I serve this file to the user?

**Algorithm:**

1. user click on button;
2. function generate file(example test.xlx);
3. when file created, file is downloaded to the user's computer;
4. finish.

Comment: It puts the file on its skin.

Comment: Create a link to the URL of that file for them to click on.  Or you can have the server send the file instead of the filename.

Comment: i believe this has been asked before. One option is to create a hidden iFrame with that url

Comment: explain how you want to serve it... load in container in same page or open new url, or create link for user? Please be less ambiguous and more detailed when posting questions

Comment: I update my question. See him again please.

Comment: Questions don't have gender.

Comment: see this please http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=ru&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=ru&twu=1&u=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539111/serving-file-to-user&usg=ALkJrhhcBlD8AO3o4FKF5tmYK7kUw-pKtA

Comment: @LeeTaylor what you do not understand?

Comment: @LeoLoki "See him again please."

Comment: me need output file for user when he click on button. when user click on button first generated file, then this file should been download to computer user. *data* have name file when should been download to computer user. What me need doing next in my code?

Comment: @LeeTaylor See question again) it should have been clear from the context.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window.location=data;
```

Will redirect to the url, and since is a download should force download and not leave page

Comment: you think that `data` have 'test.xlx', then download start(if use your code)?

Answer (score 1):

To integrate charlietfl's suggestion with your code:

```
$.post("./test.php", {
    record:id,
    opt:'code'
  },
  function(data){
      window.location=data;
  });
});
```

Try it!